# swift firebase retrieve all object that the child of the object have the same key

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Below is my firebase and code , I would like to retrieve all activities which have the User John key inside User.
[image: ss]

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("activities/")
ref.queryOrderedByChild("User").queryEqualToValue("John").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value,
        withBlock:{
            (snapshot) in

            for record in snapshot.children
            {

            }
       })
```

Comment: Please updated your results/exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not working because in your query you are trying to take all the activities having an attribute `User == "John"` when the real value of User is an Object like this:

```
{ 
  "John": {
    "age": 21
  }
}
```

To solve this issue you should change your data structure creating a node where you save all your users, and keep in `users/userID/activities` only the id of the activities. For example, this would be a nicer way to structure your data:

```
{
    "activities": {
        "cycling": {
            "users": {
                "user1": true,
                "user2": true
            }
        },
        "running": {
            "users": {
                "user1": true
            }
        }
    },
    "users": {
        "user1": {
            "name": "John",
            "age": 21,
            "activities": {
                "cycling": true,
                "running": true,
            }
        },
        "user2": {
            "name": "Tim",
            "age": 20,
            "activities": {
                "cycling": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use 
Let me know if this helped ;)

Comment: If i change my data structure to this , how to i retrieve activities that the users consist of user1. Which this case , retrieving activities "cicling" and "running"?

Comment: Ops, I've edited my answer! 
You should structure your data depending on how you want to retrieve them, so this could be a good solution